# why javascript Speech Recognition api is not working without internet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, speech-recognition

I was working with javascript speech recognition api(`new webkitSpeechRecognition()`) and i amazed why it is not working without internet since it is javascript code so it should work offline

I checked the network section of chrome developer tools, it is even not making request to internet

Comment: This is way too broad, you need to show your code at least so we can try and understand what's failing

Comment: nothing is failing, every thing is working fine but only with internet, i will add code

Answer (score 6):

On Chrome, using Speech Recognition on a web page involves a server-based recognition engine. Your audio is sent to a web service for recognition processing, so it won't work offline.

Comment: do you mean there is way to do that without internet? please tell me any other way to do the same without internet if possible, even with 50% accuracy I'm okay, it is just yes no yeah nope etc in my case

Comment: I understand that there is an alternative using the Pocket-Sphinx Python library which can work offline. More info here: https://pypi.org/project/pocketsphinx/

Then your Python code could be called using a JavaScript Ajax call or jQuery:
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "~/pythoncode.py",
  data: { param: text}
}).done(function( o ) {
   // do something
});

Comment: And here you have another Python library for that:  https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition:

> **SpeechRecognition.serviceURI**
>  Specifies the location of the speech recognition service used by the current SpeechRecognition to
>   handle the actual recognition. The default is the user agent's default
>   speech service.

The actual recognition is done by a 3rd party server.
I assume the task of speech recognition currently is just too much for a browser to cope with on it's own or requires a big database.